# Using Bitlocker with no TPM present, but instead using a USB key

Tags: windows-10, usb, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I am trying to figure this out two things when using Bitlocker by storing the encryption key on a USB drive. I would like to understand two scenarios.

Scene 1: I encrypt  the drive using bitlocker and putting the encryption key on a USB drive(due to not having a TPM module) and not using a PIN at startup. What happened if i loose my USB drive with the encryption on it?

Scene 2: Same as Scene one, but Using a PIN at startup, what would happen if i loose my USB drive or it get stolen.

Do i need the USB key to decrypt the PIN prompt screen? or is the USB key used for after the PIN has been inserted and used for the booting of the Operating System?

Comment: In both scenarios, if you lose the drive and you don't have the recovery key, you will be unable to access your data.

Comment: You can't use the PIN at startup as it is the PIN of the TPM (which you don't have). The only alternative to the USB stick is entering the 28 hexadecimal digit long recovery key.

Comment: See this page>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>https://www.howtogeek.com/262744/how-to-use-a-usb-key-to-unlock-a-bitlocker-encrypted-pc/

Comment: Thanks i am currently trying to roll out bitlocker for our company, but there's too many variables to take intoo consideration( New IT Admin to the company, with fresh ideas but too many OLD tech). OLD server operating system, device knowledge is not up to date, inventory is lacking basic information, surveying tools not being used properly. So its like finding the needle in a haystack.